# Remove enclosing P tag from around certain class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove any instance of a `<p>` tag wrapped around any element with a class of .cta.

For example:

```
<p><a href="#" class="cta">test</a></p>
```

To

```
<a href="#" class="cta">test</a>
```

I am using the code below at the moment but it is removing all P tags from within my sidebar, I'm just trying to make the jquery only target

tags that are enclosing .cta elements.

```
jQuery('.sidePanel p').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: `jQuery('.cta').unwrap();`...

Comment: This is not specific enough, would this not unwrap any divs that may be containing .cta?

Comment: _" I'm just trying to make the jquery only target tags that are enclosing `.cta` elements."_ - What you have listed above was an example as you noted. Based on your wording, specific elements to target are irrelevant. You wanted to unwrap any element enclosing any other element with a class of `cta`. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close! The `unwrap` just needs to be called on the `a`, and you don't need the call to `contents`. Here a final example line:

```
jQuery('.sidePanel .cta').unwrap();
```

And a quick live demo that you can *Inspect Element* on:

```js
jQuery('.cta').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" class="cta">test</a></p>
```

Comment: Oh man I feel dumb now, so obvious when looking at it.. Thanks

Comment: @James Glad I could help!

Comment: Would jQuery('.sidePanel p > .cta') not be even better? Only targets .cta then

Comment: @James Depending on the specificity you're looking for, that may be better for your needs. It's just a more specific way of targeting the element you're looking for, so there's no harm in it.

Answer (score 1):

To unwrap any element around an element with the class of `cta` target the elements and call `.unwrap()`:

```
jQuery('.cta').unwrap();
```

Since you're only worried about the elements around any other element with `.cta`, the specific element selector is irrelevant.

**EDIT:**

Based on the latest comment, you'll need to add an additional class to the jQuery selector to restrict the search to the sidebar:

```
jQuery('.sidePanel .cta').unwrap();
```

Comment: Only cta's within sidebar though

Comment: @James Edited to support this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('.sidePanel .cta').unwrap();
```

instead of

```
jQuery('.sidePanel p').contents().unwrap();
```